# snmpd.conf: can't exec script (Permission denied)

Tags: debian, snmpd

I am trying to exec command to perform checks through snmp.

I am on Debian 6.0

Here is my snmpd.conf file

```
rwcommunity public 172.23.129.0/29
syslocation "Blah
syscontact admin@domain.net
sysname belleville.domain.net
sysdescr "Syslog Domain Server"

disk /

load 5 10 10

#exec 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/domain/tools/check-syslog.py
exec 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/check-syslog.py
```

Here is the output of snmpget:

```
snmpget -Of -cpublic -v1 belleville 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.101.1
.iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.101.1 = STRING: "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/tmp/check-syslog.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied"
```

I don't understand the permission issue, as the rights on the file are 711 and owner root:root, located in /tmp folder.
Anyway, this script is executed by root user, isn't it? So 700 should be enough anyway?
This makes me think that this does not look like a permission trouble, even with this error message.

I hope someone has ever met this issue, and would be able to give me some advice :/

Thanks a lot for any piece of advice :)

Answer (score 2):

You've said that the script is located in `/tmp`; is your `/tmp` partition mounted `noexec` by any chance?  That can be an occasional source of confusion.

Comment: Hi, Thx for you answer, but there is nothing like that in my /tmp dir

Answer (score 2):

snmpd might run with a different accout than root as well.

Check out by executing a test-script that executes "id".

Comment: When I change the rights from 711 to 771, I still get the same problem. I have to change the rights to 777 to have an other output:

Comment: Sounds as if I am right. So what is the output of "id" after you did your 777?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, that it is exactly your problem. We ran into the same one but with `extend`, where name is required and OID isn't. So our misconfigured snmp was executing only the last part of command line which wasn't executable file.

Your variant:

```
exec 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/check-syslog.py
```

will define `/usr/bin/python` and name and try to execute only `/tmp/check-syslog.py` without interpreter

Correct one with extension name `check-syslog`:

```
exec 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8 check-syslog /usr/bin/python /tmp/check-syslog.py
```

Comment: Your final example is clear and precisely what I needed in my situation.  I wasn't having the issue you were having but other examples I've seen didn't have both the OID and the "extension name".  +1